# Authenticating with JIRA

Tags: java, rest, jira

Hi I building an application in JAVA to grab information from JIRA by performing several rest requests, but i'm running into trouble with one where authentication is needed.  From the JIRA web page i have found this https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Basic+Authentication. But i'm running into problems figuring out how to do this in java, and if there is another way that would be great.

Comment: Ask Atlassian folks on their forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Jira REST Java Client Library](https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JRJC), here is a [tutorial](https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JRJC/Tutorial) to get you started.